# Google test Gtest.cc:812: error: 'gettimeofday' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, mingw

I am trying to compile Google test through MinGW via command line, but when I try to compile with command

```
gcc -I D:\gtest -I D:\gtest\include -I D:\gtest\include\gtest src\gtest_main.cc src\gtest-all.cc
```

it throws error

`Gtest.cc:812: error: 'gettimeofday' was not declared in this scope`

I successfully compiled through Visual Studio, so my guess it's not the fault in code. Does anyone else encountered this problem and knows solution?

Comment: Do you mean `gettimeofday`? Or where has `gettimeoftheday` come from?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I fixed that

Comment: Did you `#include <sys/time.h>`? Show us the code.

Comment: Here you go, [gtest.cc](http://pastebin.com/stEUyPJ8)

Comment: Note: `<time.h>` and `<sys/time.h>` are two different includes..

Answer (score 5):

`<time.h> and <sys/time.h>` are two different includes

Comment: Definitely answered my question! And certainly could have answered OP's.